# How do I import a named file from a zip folder from Gmail to Sheets using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recently been trying to import a folder from a zip file into sheets. I have tried the below code but it only returns the first file. I have tried multiple ways to get it to return a file by name but to no avail.

Please would someone be able to show me how I can get the script to search the extracted folder for a certain file and import that instead.

```
function getCSV() {
var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Auction_HVT");
var threads = myLabel.getThreads(0,1);
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();



var csv =  attachments[0];
var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);
var attachmentName = extracted.getName()
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string);




var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("HVT");
sheet.clearContents();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);


     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve a file (CSV file) from a zip file by searching the filename.
- You want to put the CSV data from the retrieved file.

In this case, how about the following modification? `Utilities.unzip()` returns `Blob[]`. So you can search the specific file from `Blob[]`.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
var csv =  attachments[0];
var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);
var attachmentName = extracted.getName()
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string);
```

##### To:

```js
var searchFilename = "sample.csv"; // Please set the filename of the CSV file you want to retrieve.

var csv =  attachments[0].setContentTypeFromExtension();
var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);
var csv = extracted.find(e => e.getName().slice(-searchFilename.length) == searchFilename);
if (!csv) {
  throw new Error(searchFilename + " was not found.");
}
var string = csv.getDataAsString();
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string);
```

#### References:

- [unzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @Christopher Wilkinson Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my modified script, when the search filename is not found, an error occurs. So from `doesn't throw up any errors.`, it is considered that the file could be retrieved. So in this case, when you put `console.log(string)` after the line of `var string = csv.getDataAsString();` and run the script, what values will you see? If the CSV data is shown in the log, `data` is put to the sheet of `HVT` sheet. How about this?

Comment: All working fine now, do you happen to know how I would get the script to delete older attachments as I get this report every 30 minutes and don't want it to fill my storage space.

Comment: @Christopher Wilkinson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?